# Oracle SQL How to break down income by month based on a date range?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Trying to find an efficient way of achieving the results in table B below based on data from table A. Is there an efficient way (i.e. not resource hungry) of doing so assuming one has millions of such records in table A? Please note ID 1 has an end date of 12/31/2199 (not a typo), and we only list the income for each ID during the months of 09/2016 to 12/2016. Also note that ID 3 has two incomes in the month of 11/2016, with 600 representing the November income (since that's the income the ID had at the end of November 2016 month). As for IDs that started in say November 2016, their rows would be missing for Sept 16 and Oct 16 since they did not exist pre-November.

Table A:

```
ID  INCOME  EFFECTIVE_DATE  END_DATE
1   700     07/01/2016      12/31/2199
2   500     08/20/2016      12/31/2017
3   600     11/11/2016      02/28/2017
3   100     09/01/2016      11/10/2016
4   400     11/21/2016      12/31/2016
```

Table B (Intended results):

```
         
ID  INCOME  MONTH
1   700     12/2016
1   700     11/2016
1   700     10/2016
1   700     09/2016
2   500     12/2016
2   500     11/2016
2   500     10/2016
2   500     09/2016
3   600     12/2016
3   600     11/2016
3   100     10/2016
3   100     09/2016
4   400     12/2016
4   400     11/2016
```

**RESOLVED** I used the answer provided by @mathguy below and it worked like a charm -- learned something new in this process: pivot and unpivot. Also thanks to @MTO (and everyone else) for taking the time to help.

Comment: OK - it seems "income" is not pro-rated? In many cases table A shows a monthly salary, but table B shows only 1/3 of that if the employee was hired on November 21 (November has 30 days, and they were there for 10 days, so they get only 1/3 of salary). If this is something you didn't think about, best find out NOW, before people start posting answers. Also, if an "ID" started in November 2016, should they also have rows for Sept and Oct in table B (with `null` income) or should those rows be missing?

Comment: thanks @mathguy. so if the employee was hired on Nov 21 (with income of say 200 -- income does not change, it is as-displayed in table A), their ID in table A would show with income of 200 with an effective date of 11/21/2016 with an end date of say 02/28/2017, so their income for the month of November 2016 would be 200, and so it would be for 12/2016. As for ID that started in November 2016, their rows would be missing for Sept and Oct since they did not exist pre-November.

Comment: OK... so I see if ID = 3 has been there the entire month of November, their "income" is dictated by the end of the month. What if an employee left on Dec. 20 - do they even have a row for December? Or is everything dependent ENTIRELY on the END of the month?

Comment: By the way, regardless of the exact requirement, the problem does have an efficient solution, taking advantage of UNPIVOT. I was almost done with a solution when I noticed this aspect, of "income" changing in the middle of a month.

Comment: @mathguy for this purpose a scenario where an employee leaves on Dec 20(and no other dates after that) would not be represented in table A. All the data in table A follows the pattern above. Someone who has an income with an end date that falls somewhere in the month, will surely have another row entry with an effective that picks up from that previous row's end date e.g. ID #3 above

Comment: OK. What I posted picks up end-of-month income in all cases. (Zero for October if they left, say, on Oct. 20.) If this is not a concern, so much the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses each row from the base table just once, and does not require joins, group by, etc. It uses the `unpivot` operation, available since Oracle 11.1, which is not an expensive operation.

```
with
     table_a ( id, income, effective_date, end_date ) as (
       select 1, 700, date '2016-07-01', date '2199-12-31' from dual union all
       select 2, 500, date '2016-08-20', date '2017-12-31' from dual union all
       select 3, 600, date '2016-11-11', date '2017-02-28' from dual union all
       select 3, 100, date '2016-09-01', date '2016-11-10' from dual union all
       select 4, 400, date '2016-11-21', date '2016-12-31' from dual
     )
-- end of test data (not part of the solution): SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select id, income, mth
from (
       select id,
              case when date '2016-09-30' between effective_date and end_date
                   then income end as sep16,
              case when date '2016-10-31' between effective_date and end_date
                   then income end as oct16,
              case when date '2016-11-30' between effective_date and end_date
                   then income end as nov16,
              case when date '2016-12-31' between effective_date and end_date
                   then income end as dec16
       from   table_a
     )
unpivot ( income for mth in ( sep16 as '09/2016', oct16 as '10/2016', nov16 as '11/2016',
                              dec16 as '12/2016' )
        )
order by id, mth desc
;
```

**Output**:

```
ID INCOME MTH
-- ------ -------
 1    700 12/2016
 1    700 11/2016
 1    700 10/2016
 1    700 09/2016
 2    500 12/2016
 2    500 11/2016
 2    500 10/2016
 2    500 09/2016
 3    600 12/2016
 3    600 11/2016
 3    100 10/2016
 3    100 09/2016
 4    400 12/2016
 4    400 11/2016

14 rows selected.
```

Comment: thanks! works like a charm. with this structure though, how would i go about joining another table if the common element between them was the ID? can that be done?

Comment: @DaveJabbz - You can join just like you would join in any other case. Go ahead and try - and write back if you run into any problems.

Comment: just under table_a in the structure above, and within the 'with' clause, i have another table as such:<pre><code>cases as (SELECT ID, CASE_NUMBER, APPLICATION_DATE FROM TABLE_D)</code></pre> I'd like to join this 'cases' to the rest of the query(table_a etc using the ID and also pull back the case_number and application date) but I seem to get a 'command not properly ended' error no matter where i place the join.

Comment: i think I figured it out. i provided an alias to the above main select statement and added the other tables and joins just before the 'order by'. seems to work.

Comment: I don't follow. Why do you have a `with` clause in **your** query? I used it in mine, just to mimic your base table - don't you have a base table (or view, or result of another query) that you would use there? In any case, a WITH clause must appear at the top of a SELECT statement - it must appear before any FROM clause.

Comment: Correct, I do have a base table, and using this approach and without a with clause, it worked perfectly. Sorry I was not clear before. I thereafter created a with clause, added additional tables under this with clause and above the select statement as you have it above and joined them to the base table. So using your approach and the additional functionality I added, all worked fine in the end.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a recursive sub-query factoring clause. This does not rely on hard-coding the bounds into the query as they can be passed as the bind variable `:lower_bound` and `:upper_bound`; in the example below they are set to `DATE '2016-09-01'` and `DATE '2016-12-31'` respectively.

**Query**:

```
WITH months ( id, income, month, end_dt ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         income,
         CAST( TRUNC( GREATEST( a.effective_date, :lower_bound ), 'MM' ) AS DATE ),
         LEAST( a.end_date, :upper_bound )
  FROM   TableA a
  WHERE  :lower_bound <= a.end_date
  AND    a.effective_date <= :upper_bound
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         income,
         CAST( ADD_MONTHS( month, 1 ) AS DATE ),
         end_dt
  FROM   months
  WHERE  ADD_MONTHS( month, 1 ) <= end_dt
)
SELECT id,
       income,
       LAST_DAY( month ) AS month
FROM   months
WHERE  LAST_DAY( month ) <= end_dt
ORDER BY id, month;
```

**Output**:

```
ID INCOME MONTH
-- ------ ----------
 1    700 2016-09-30
 1    700 2016-10-31
 1    700 2016-11-30
 1    700 2016-12-31
 2    500 2016-09-30
 2    500 2016-10-31
 2    500 2016-11-30
 2    500 2016-12-31
 3    100 2016-09-30
 3    100 2016-10-31
 3    600 2016-11-30
 3    600 2016-12-31
 4    400 2016-11-30
 4    400 2016-12-31
```

Comment: This solution is more general than the hard-coded one I offered; however, due to the recursive query, it will be more resource-hungry. The OP specifically mentioned that as a concern. If that is indeed a severe problem, then I would go with the hard-coded months and the `UNPIVOT` approach (which, on the other hand, **does not work** if at least the number of months to be considered is not set in advance).